Can the graph of a rational function cross oblique asymptotes
I have a follow up question from my previous one: I was told that horizontal asymptotes can be crossed by the graphs of rational functions (and I discovered that the vertical ones can't be crossed). At this point I was wondering whether the oblique ones can be crossed at any point by the graph of the rational function from which we found those oblique asymptotes.

Yes it can. Example $$x+\frac x{x^2+1}.$$https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%2Cx%2Bx%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29

The graph of the function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{x^3-5x+1}{x^2+1}
\end{equation}
crosses its oblique asymptote $y=x$.
Note that $f$ is continuous and $f(-1) = 2.5 > -1$ and $f(1) = -1.5 < 1$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x\in (-1,1)$ such that $f(x)=x$.

So the answer is yes correct? but the thing we should be looking at is how it behaves towards the extremes of the graph right? Thanks

@FedericoRuck The intersection points between the curve and the asymptote are solutions of a polynomial equation, which has only a finite number of solutions. It means that when $|x|$ is large enough, the function and its asymptote don't cross (unless the function is equal to its asymptote).
